# Java int and long : how to change the most significant bit?

Tags: java, int, bit-manipulation, long-integer

For fun, I've been implementing the DES algorithm in java. (Well, it's not that fun actually).
In the algorithm, you handle blocks of 64 bites of data, and I thought : hey, it's perfect, let's use "long" to store my binary data.

I then run into a serious trouble that kind of pisses me off : let's say you build a long, like this :

```
long value = 785537;
```

Let's say that you want to set the most significant bit of you value to 1, you would do something like that :

```
value |= 0x8000000000000000l;
```

Pretty straightforward, right ?
But it's not working at all. Java has no trouble changing another bit, which means that

```
value |= 0x7000000000000000l;
```

will work. But it won't work if it's the most significant bit.

Why ? Is there some way to achieve what I want ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Edit :

Here is a sample of a code I wrote, to display a long in a binary form :

```
public static void printBits(long input){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        if((input & (0x1l << i)) != 0){
            builder.append('1');
        } else {
            builder.append('0');
        }
    }

    System.out.println(builder);
}
```

If I do this :

```
long val = -1;
printBits(val);
```

It will print "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110" as it's supposed to.
If I then type :

```
val |= Long.MIN_VALUE;
printBits(val);
```

Or

```
val |= 0x8000000000000000l;
printBits(val);
```

It's printing "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110" also...

If then do the following test :

```
(val & 8000000000000000l) != 0;
```

It's false...

Comment: In what way is is "not working at all"?

Comment: How are you verifying whether it is working or not?

Comment: If it's not a number, but data, I would use `unsigned long`

Comment: Please post your test program and output, indicating what you expect vs what you see.

Comment: btw, `value |= 0x7000000000000000l;` won't change just a single bit since 7d is 111b

Comment: @SarwarErfan IIRC there is no `unsigned` in java.

Comment: @CAFxX your right, but it still works the way it's supposed to :)

Comment: @CAFxX: oh ya.. this is tagged java.. now I see the title says java also

Comment: `value |=  0x8000000000000000L;` works for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class LongMsb {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long value = 785537;
    System.out.printf("%016x\n", value);
    value |= Long.MIN_VALUE;
    System.out.printf("%016x\n", value);
  }
}
```

Using

```
value |= 0x8000000000000000l;
```

or

```
value |= 1L << 63;
```

instead of

```
value |= Long.MIN_VALUE;
```

also works and is probably somewhat more readable.

Both print the following:

```
00000000000bfc81
80000000000bfc81
```

Comment: The mask should be written as (1L << 63). That would be more readable. Otherwise you have to count the zeros.

Comment: I apologize for my question : I'm probably tired, and made stupid mistakes using a mask and older versions of my code. Which means : there's actually no problem at all, just a stupid tired developer that rushed Stackoverflow too soon. Anyway, thanks for your answers. I selected Alan Zalcman answer because it taught me something about printing hex strings.

Comment: That's right. I've added your suggestion. Note that () aren't needed as assignment has one of the lowest precedence among operators in java.

Answer (score 0):

The number represented by the most significant bit would be the minimal value for long, so that would be:

```
long mask = Long.MIN_VALUE;
```

Then to use that mask to invert the most significant bit, you can use bitwise xor:

```
long value  = 785537;
value ^= mask;
```

**EDIT:** I misread, I thought you wanted to invert the most significant bit; for simply setting it, your approach is correct:

```
value |= mask;
```

Comment: Hum, I just want to use a long number as a container of 64 bits... I'm not really interested in the most significant bit per say, it's just that I can't change it, and therefore my container is only a 63 bit container...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly; you can change the most significant bit of a long with the above approach; is that not what you were looking for?

Comment: Oh, I think you do want inversion! If you want val to have a leading zero after the bitwise comparison, use bitwise xor as I described.

Comment: Thanks again for your concern, I just realized that my question was rushed and stupid : the problem lied elsewhere in the code...